# Can't join node to cluster (Kubernetes)

Tags: kubernetes, etcd

When I run `kubeadm join` everything seems to be fine in output, but pod for this node has `CrashLoopBackOff` status because of the following error in logs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 336, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 287, in main
  File "<string>", line 210, in warn_if_hostname_conflict
  File "site-packages/pycalico/datastore.py", line 137, in wrapped
pycalico.datastore_errors.DataStoreError: get_host_bgp_ips: Error accessing etcd (Connection to etcd failed due to MaxRetryError("HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=2379): Max retries exceeded with url: /v2/keys/calico/bgp/v1/host/bpmw05/ip_addr_v4 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f1872c364d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))",)).  Is etcd running?
startup returned -1
Waiting for etcd connection...
No IP provided. Using detected IP: 192.168.56.105
Calico node failed to start

NAMESPACE     NAME                                    READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
default       my-nginx-379829228-0pf4b                1/1       Running            0          1h
kube-system   calico-node-7wodf                       2/2       Running            0          2h
kube-system   calico-node-s7dyu                       1/2       CrashLoopBackOff   6          6m
kube-system   calico-policy-controller-modx4          1/1       Running            0          2h
kube-system   dummy-2088944543-jl2fu                  1/1       Running            0          2h
kube-system   etcd-host                               1/1       Running            0          2h
kube-system   kube-apiserver-host                     1/1       Running            0          2h
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-host            1/1       Running            0          2h
kube-system   kube-discovery-1150918428-asto0         1/1       Running            0          2h
kube-system   kube-dns-654381707-rvt9o                3/3       Running            0          2h
kube-system   kube-proxy-f7v9u                        1/1       Running            0          6m
kube-system   kube-proxy-x58jy                        1/1       Running            0          2h
kube-system   kube-scheduler-host                     1/1       Running            0          2h
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-3095304083-9moev   1/1       Running            0          53m
```

May be some additional setup for etcd is required?
(I am using [this](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/kubeadm/) tutorial as a reference and running on CentOS 7.2 VMs managed by VMware ESXi.)

I can confirm that etcd is running on master by folowing command:

```
http://127.0.0.1:2379/version
{"etcdserver":"2.2.5","etcdcluster":"2.2.0"}
```

But as far as I understand other nodes also should have access to it? Or not? If I try to curl from node on which join command was run I get Connection refused (I use IP of master node instead of localhost). Like so:

```
curl -s http://[master_ip]:2379/version
[no output]
```

Comment: It seems like your node is not able to talk to `etcd` on 127.0.0.1 (localhost). I would check if it is running, or make sure the node has joined the etcd cluster first.

Comment: @MrE, regarding join to etcd. Should I take some additional step to join node to etcd cluster before running `kubeadm join`? I didn't see any reference to this in the guide.

Comment: The guide may assume a 3 node cluster like many guides, and if etcd is not configured on every node, trying to reach it on 127.0.0.1 will fail. So check if etcd is running on your new node. if not, maybe start it.

Comment: try `etcdctl cluster-health` and `etcdctl member list` to see what's going on. as well as check logs / journal to see if there is anything wrong with etcd. but your error states it can't reach etcd on that node, so i would start there.

Comment: @MrE, Thank you. It looks like I have installed everything with `kubeadm` utility and `etcdctl` is not on the `$PATH`. Also, I have no etcd cluster in my setup as far as I understand. Nodes should talk to master for persistence (at least it looks so). [Official tutorial](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/kubeadm/) definitely is missing something.

Comment: Kubernetes uses etcd as the backend for keeping state, so it's either running on the host, or maybe itself running in a container bootstrapped with early-docker. Try `docker ps` to see what's running in containers, or look for the etcdctl utility on your host.

Comment: @MrE, As I understand from the [docs](http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/etcd/) etcd is running in dedicated POD on master. You can see it in the original question as `etcd-host`. And I can access it from master with curl via `http://127.0.0.1:2379`. It seems node should not have direct access to etcd (only master has it). From the docs `Access Control: give only kube-apiserver read/write access to etcd.`

Comment: from the doc, `kubeadm` is in alpha, and has a bunch of limitations. You probably should try the repo to report bugs.
http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/kubeadm/#limitations